Change the title and URL on the main page when clicking on a link in the iframe
I need your help, I have a parent A page with an integrated B iframe.
When I click on a link in the B iframe, I want to retrieve the title and url of the clicked link and pass it to the main page to simulate navigation.
It's essential that the page doesn't reload.
To do this, I use the javascript message API and the history API.
This works fine, but my history doesn't work properly anymore, as I have to click twice on previous for it to work.
Or I can't get the corresponding url in the url bar.
I know that what I'm trying to do is rather complicated, but if anyone has a solution or a clue, I'd love to hear from you.
Thanks in advance
Main page :
  <iframe id="childFrame1" name="childFrame1" src="child1.html" width="600" height="400"></iframe>

    <script>
        // Ajoute un gestionnaire pour l'événement popstate dans le parent
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
            alert('pop')
            console.log(event.state)

              if (event.state && event.state.url) {
                const iframe = document.querySelector("#childFrame1");
                iframe.src = event.state.url;
            }
        });

        // Écoute les messages provenant des iframes
        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            if (event.data.type === 'updateUrl') {
                // Met à jour l'URL et le titre sans ajouter une nouvelle entrée à l'historique
                history.pushState({ url: event.data.url, title: event.data.title, source: event.data.source }, event.data.title, event.data.url);

                document.title = event.data.title;
            }
        });


    </script>

Iframe code:
<a href="/page1" data-title="Page 1">Link to Page 1</a>
    <a href="/page2" data-title="Page 2">Link to Page 2</a>

    <script>

      function navigate(url, title) {
        window.parent.postMessage(
          {
            type: "updateUrl",
            url: url,
            title: title,
            source: "iframe"
          },
          "*"
        );
      }

      // Gestion des boutons
      document.getElementById("navigate1").addEventListener("click", function () {
        navigate("/page1", "Page 1");
      });

      document.getElementById("navigate2").addEventListener("click", function () {
        navigate("/page2", "Page 2");
      });

      // Gestion des liens
      document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // Empêche le comportement par défaut
          navigate(link.getAttribute('href'), link.getAttribute('data-title'));
 location.assign(link.href);
        });
      });
    </script>

From what I've read, the only way to change the url is to use pushState, which is a problem in my case.

the only way to change the url is to use pushState, which is a problem in my case why?

Navigating inside the iframe creates one entry in the history, and your pushState in the main page creates a second one. That second entry could only be avoided, if you used replaceState instead - but then the entry for the navigation inside the iframe would be the one that gets replaced, so clicking the "back" button would only make your main page go one entry back, and not revert the iframe to its previous state, I suppose.

@CBroe That's right, it's an avenue I've already explored :(

@JaromandaX The problem is that if I could change the url without going through the history, I could manage it manually.

What do you mean with "pass it to the main page to simulate navigation"?
One possibility is to have JavaScript capture the URL path and never change the page so that the IFrame does not update.
The highest voted answer of that Q might help: How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?

What I mean is that on my main page A which has a url like https://test.com.
I want that if I click on a link in my iframe of the type https://iframe.com, the url is transmitted in the main url bar and that the history always works.
This would result in a https://iframe.com url in the main page.
